# Does Google Maps fitBounds() regenerate the map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fitbounds

I always used to work with [panTo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.panTo) instead of [setCenter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setCenter) to recenter a Google map because I read somewhere that using `panTo` is not being counted as a new daily usage of map (to consider the daily limitation of using google map on my website) but I don't remember where I read that.

Now I am using [fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds) and I am not sure if this method regenerates a new map too?

How can I find out which methods (e.g. `setZoom` or `fitBounds`) produce a new map? Does `fitBounds`?

Comment: `new google.maps.Map(...)` creates a new map.  Methods that change the center or zoom (like `fitBounds`, `panTo`, `setCenter`, `setZoom`,...), don't create a new map.

Comment: I know that `google.maps.map()` is the only code to start a new map however `setCenter` loads the map content again (with a blink) when you move to far target but panTo does not. Do you confirm that `setCenter` is not counted in daily limits of google maps? @geocodezip

Comment: I am not Google.

Comment: Just [read the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#dynamic-maps) it clearly says what counts and is billed as a new map instance and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The `fitBounds()` method does not create a new map, it just sets the viewport to contain the given map bounds.

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#dynamic-maps) states the following:

> SKU: Dynamic Maps
>
> A web page or application that displays a map using the Maps
> JavaScript API. A map is created with the **google.maps.Map()** class.
>
> User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching
> map layers, **do not generate additional map loads**.

You may also refer to [this FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload) to understand how map loads are counted.

Hope this answers your concern.